# Rather then a company published manga, can a self-published manga become an adapted anime?

Tags: anime-production, anime-history, manga-production, manga-history

Did it ever happen before when self-published mangas become adapted into an anime without having mangas published by companies?

Comment: "Can" Of course it can. If someone with enough money would be crazy enough to sponsor the production. But it would be extremely risky. It would be cheaper and safer to publish the manga (or novel if it is writing).

Comment: Money is involved in almost every step.  Sure, being self published and able to get an anime would be phenomenal, but it requires an inordinate amount of resources.

Comment: @Makoto compared to self published or published(by company) manga why is it hard for a self published manga to get a anime adaptation?

Comment: Actually, there are many self-published manga (doujinshi) that got adapted into anime, but most of them are OVA/ONA which are not streamed on the TV, only in form of VOD/CD/DVD/BD. That said, the reason is popularity & money. Most of them are already popular, and producing an anime adaptation may be worthwhile. For the rest though, it might hurt their financial.

Comment: [Anime Planet have based-on-doujinshi tag](https://www.anime-planet.com/anime/tags/based-on-a-doujinshi) although the list is probably not complete

Answer (score 5):

There are a few anime adaptations of doujins and Artist CGs, like Z-Ton's "A Beautiful Greed" and Maron Maron's "Yareruko! Densha Ecchi", both of these are NSFW. Also that short anime "Getsuyoubi no Tawawa" was based on illustrations Himura Kiseki posted on pixiv that later got released as compilations on Comiket, so this is a doujin as well. Those are the only ones that come to mind at the moment but I'm pretty sure there should be a few more. It doesn't happen that often though, it's more of an exception to the norm.

Comment: Haibane Renmei supposedly was based off a doujin the director wrote too, I think, but I'm unsure of the details.