# Can doujinshi get anime adaptations? Also can they become "real" Manga if good enough

Tags: anime-production, manga-production, doujinshi

Was wondering if doujinshi can get an anime adaptations and become real manga that are officially sold by companies.

Comment: Dupe for the first question: [Rather then a company published manga, can a self-published manga become an adapted anime?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/41182)

Comment: [Anime Planet have based-on-doujinshi tag](https://www.anime-planet.com/anime/tags/based-on-a-doujinshi) although the list is probably not complete

Answer (score 12):

If by "doujinshi" you mean "self-published manga that parody other published works" (probably the most restrictive definition), the answer is yes. Examples:

- *Nyoron Churuya-san* (a *Suzumiya Haruhi no Yuuutsu* doujin)

If you loosen the definition to "self-published manga", there are even more examples:

- *Sore ga Seiyuu!*
- *Getsuyoubi no Tawawa*

If you go further and consider *all* self-published works (including webcomics and text-only media), there are even more:

- *Maoyuu Maou Yuusha* (originally a series of posts on 2ch)
- *Isekai wa Smartphone to Tomo ni* (originally posted on "Shousetsuka ni Narou")
- *Re:Zero* (likewise)
- *One Punch Man* (originally a webcomic)

This is by no means a rare phenomenon. Self-published stuff that becomes popular gets commercialized pretty often.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Example: Yoshitoshi Abe's, [Haibane Renmei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haibane_Renmei).

Comment: Welcome to [anime.se]. While this might be the answer, could you expand a little bit, perhaps by explaining a short history of this doujinshi turned into anime and manga? You can always [edit] to improve your post. Also, consider taking a quick [tour] to know more how this site works.

Answer (score 0):

Yup.

Afro Samurai was a Doujin before being produced into an animated series, being self published through the magazine *Nou Nou Hau*

Any production company can pick up any work, regardless of who published it, as long as the right people give consent and are paid.